# Handle cancel subscription in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, in-app-subscription

I was using Unity's In-app purchase API to implement subscription in my app.

I want to trigger the cancel subscription without reinstalling the app. How can I track the unsubscriptions done by users from Google Play Store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the late update but unity provided me with the solution.

[Improved Support for Subscription Products](https://forum.unity.com/threads/improved-support-for-subscription-products.532811/)